# Найти погрешность функции

Tags: математика, численные-методы

> Оценить абсолютную и относительную погрешность вычисления величины F,
>   если для  x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub> погрешность  Δ = 0.007
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, нужно найти абсолютную погрешность от возведения в степень

```
step*pow(x,step-1)*absolute_error
```

при операциях сложения/вычитания/умножения просто добавлять абсолютные погрешности, а что делать с `exp( 8* x2 – x1 )` ?

В результате будет получена абсолютная погрешность и получив число - после подстановки x-ов можно найти относительную погрешность ? Или для функций это не работает ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще говоря, обычно для `F(x)` при погрешности `x`, равной `Δx`, погрешность значения функции равна `ΔF = dF/dx * Δx`. Для функции от нескольких переменных - для каждой переменной берутся частные производные, а погрешности от разных переменных, если не ошибаюсь, суммируются как ортогональные - т.е. корень из суммы квадратов.

Насчет производных уверен, насчет квадратов - уверен на 90% :)